# Bootstrap 3 button dropdown displays list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a Bootstrap [button dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single). I followed the directions from the docs:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The dropdown displays the list items on my page:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine on Bootply so probably some styles either missing or being overwritten/changed http://www.bootply.com/nExT1Rwbtv

Comment: Are you using the prototype.js library in your project? It causes some weird behavior with bootstrap.

Comment: I wasn't including the CSS and JS correctly, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

working fine when i include all  the boostrap files, May be you missed some css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bootply snippet - Bootply Bootstrap Preview</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- CSS code from Bootply.com editor -->
     
    </head>
    
    <!-- HTML code from Bootply.com editor -->
    
    <body  >
        
        <div class="btn-group">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>  <ul class="dropdown-menu">    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>  </ul></div>
        
        <script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <script type='text/javascript' src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right, I wasn't properly including the JS and CSS. This fixed it, thank you!